# Easiest way to install Python 3.3.6? (without a build)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Installing python 3.4 from python.org is a breeze - it downloads a .msi file and next thing I know, I have python installed on my C drive. However, I want to install python 3.3 since I want to use PyScripter and from what I understand, PyScripter does not work with python 3.4.

I went to this page: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-336/ and I only have an option to download a "tarball". From what I understand of the readme files, I need to build python from here, which I have never done (and it does not seem that straightforward)..

There is msi installer for python 3.3.5 though: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/

Python.org states that 3.3.6 is only a security update to 3.3.5 - so if possible it would be nice to install 3.3.6

How can I most easily install 3.3.6? If there is no easy way is there really any concern with 3.3.5?

Comment: You can check [the changelog](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v3.3.6/Misc/NEWS) to see what exactly is new in the .6 release. It’s apparent that they think these changes don’t justify a new binary release, and I kind of agree that you should be fine with just using 3.3.5 here.

Comment: Thanks - this is reassuring. I presume that it is a lot of work (and testing) to make an official .msi file and this is why they may not have made one for this python version?

Comment: @whatIS I doubt it really takes that much effort. In my answer - it's probably simply because it only changes python source code. No binaries to update means a full-blown install is probably overkill.

Comment: As an aside, if you're really interested in an IDE you might look at [Ninja IDE](http://ninja-ide.org/) or [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/).

Personally I'm just a fan of Vim & a command prompt or two (actually I just have VirtualBox so I can run i3wm docker - but I'm crazy like that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When 3.4.0 was released, the normal maintainance of 3.3.x ceased. This is standard policy.  However, source only security fixes will be made until 5 years after 3.3.0 (also standard policy).  The 'security' fixes are aimed at servers running on Python, and accepting input from random people on the net.  People running such servers generally compile their own binaries, and usually run on linux, etc, rather than windows.  You should be fine for your purposes with the last Windows installer.

PS. comment 25 on [this forum](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=768) claims to have PyScriptor running on 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the page you linked](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-336/), as Pierre mentioned it states

> This is a security-fix source-only release

As far as I can tell that means that the only changes *are to python source files*. Meaning there will be no benefit to having an actual installer since the only changes are in `.py` (probably) files.

It also states:

> The list of fixed security related issues can be found in the [NEWS file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v3.3.6/Misc/NEWS).

If you're too lazy to click that link, here's the relevant portion:

```
Core and Builtins
-----------------

- Issue #22518: Fixed integer overflow issues in "backslashreplace",
  "xmlcharrefreplace", and "surrogatepass" error handlers.

- Issue #22520: Fix overflow checking when generating the repr of a unicode
  object.

- Issue #22519: Fix overflow checking in PyBytes_Repr.

- Issue #22518: Fix integer overflow issues in latin-1 encoding.

Library
-------

- Issue #22517: When a io.BufferedRWPair object is deallocated, clear its
  weakrefs.

- Issue #22419: Limit the length of incoming HTTP request in wsgiref server to
  65536 bytes and send a 414 error code for higher lengths. Patch contributed
  by Devin Cook.

- Lax cookie parsing in http.cookies could be a security issue when combined
  with non-standard cookie handling in some Web browsers.  Reported by
  Sergey Bobrov.

- Issue #21766: Prevent a security hole in CGIHTTPServer by URL unquoting paths
  before checking for a CGI script at that path.

- Fix arbitrary memory access in JSONDecoder.raw_decode with a negative second
  parameter. Bug reported by Guido Vranken.

- Issue #20633: Replace relative import by absolute import.

- Issue #21082: In os.makedirs, do not set the process-wide umask. Note this
  changes behavior of makedirs when exist_ok=True.

- Issue #20875: Prevent possible gzip "'read' is not defined" NameError.
  Patch by Claudiu Popa.

- Issue #11599: When an external command (e.g. compiler) fails, distutils now
  prints out the whole command line (instead of just the command name) if the
  environment variable DISTUTILS_DEBUG is set.

- Issue #4931: distutils should not produce unhelpful "error: None" messages
  anymore.  distutils.util.grok_environment_error is kept but doc-deprecated.

- Issue #20283: RE pattern methods now accept the string keyword parameters
  as documented.  The pattern and source keyword parameters are left as
  deprecated aliases.

- Issue #21323: Fix http.server to again handle scripts in CGI subdirectories,
  broken by the fix for security issue #19435.  Patch by Zach Byrne.

Tests
-----

- Issue #17752: Fix distutils tests when run from the installed location.

- Issue #20946: Correct alignment assumptions of some ctypes tests.

- Issue #20939: Fix test_geturl failure in test_urllibnet due to
  new redirect of http://www.python.org/ to https://www.python.org.
```

You'll have to decide for yourself - do you care about those issues? If so, you should be able to just extract the tarball and copy over the python source - probably just merge the `lib` directories. If you're really conscientious you'd run a diff on the appropriate directories to identify the files and their actual changes.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I appreciate your summary on this. BTW, no I'm not lazy, I just am not a full-blown programmer that knows all terms and I do not regularly work with python. Reading the above there is no way I would have known that that is the "relevant portion" (unless I did a loooot of research).